# Postback of VM returns Null object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, post, razor

Iv populated a bicycleOrder list and passed it to the view. I then run through the list and display all the orders on screen. Each order has a checkBox for whether the order has been shipping or not. I can click or unclick the checkbox but when I submit. why does it pass 15 bicycleOrder records all containing NULL values to the post. There are 15 records in the db table but why is each value in each record being posted back as NULL?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BuyABicycle_Entities db1 = new BuyABicycle_Entities();

    List<Bicycle_Order> PopulatedOrderList = new List<Bicycle_Order>();

    List<BicycleOrder> All_Orders = (from c in db1.BicycleOrders
                                     where c.Id >= 1
                                     select c).ToList();

    foreach (BicycleOrder bik in All_Orders)
    {
        Bicycle_Order new_bik = new Bicycle_Order 
        {
            CustomerName = bik.CustomerName,
            CustomerAddress = bik.CustomerAddress,
            CustomerEmail = bik.CustomerEmail,
            CustomerPhoneNumber = bik.CustomerPhoneNumber,
            BicycleColour = bik.BicycleColour,
            BicycleModel = bik.BicycleModel,
            BicycleSize = bik.BicycleSize,
            Shipped = bik.Shipped
        };

        PopulatedOrderList.Add(new_bik);
    }

    SupplierVM model = new SupplierVM { allOrders = PopulatedOrderList };

    return View(model);
}      

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SupplierVM model)
{
    //write code:
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {          
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**VM**

```
public class SupplierVM
{
    public List<Bicycle_Order> allOrders { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model BicycleShop.ViewModels.SupplierVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Supplier";
    var orders = (List<BicycleShop.Models.Bicycle_Order>)Model.allOrders;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
    <table class="items" summary="@("This is a table of all the orders for bicycles")">
        <colgroup>
            <col id="Col1" />
            <col id="Col2" />
            <col id="Col3" />
            <col id="Col4" />
            <col id="Col5" />
            <col id="Col6" />
            <col id="Col7" />
            <col id="Col8" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Name")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Address")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Phone")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Email")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Model")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Size")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Colour")</th>
                <th scope="col" width="15%">@("Shipped")</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.allOrders.Count; i++)
    {
    <text>
       <tr>
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].CustomerName</td>   
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].CustomerAddress</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].CustomerPhoneNumber</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].CustomerEmail</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].BicycleModel</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].BicycleSize</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.allOrders[i].BicycleColour</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.allOrders[i].Shipped)</td>            
       </tr>
    </text>
    }   
    </table>
     <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Update" />
     </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

---

Can someone please tell me why on the post back (SupplierVM post) returns the correct amount of BicycleOrders in the 'allOrders' list, but each value is NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `null` because there are no input elements with unique name attributes associated with your form collection. Asp.NET MVC model binding uses your input elements' name attribute to bind your form data to your model collection. If you would have looked at your pagesource you would understand how the control names are generated for these two approaches. Change your `foreach` like below

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   <text>
   <tr>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].CustomerName)</td>   
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].CustomerAddress)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].CustomerPhoneNumber)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].CustomerEmail)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].BicycleModel)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].BicycleSize)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].BicycleColour)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model[i].Shipped)</td>
        <td width="15%">@Html.CheckBoxFor(item => Model[i].Shipped)</td>            
   </tr>
   </text>
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply Dennis. I have tried what you suggested and there are 15 record in the Order table and it is posting back 15 records to the controller. but every records columns/values are returning NULL (which is incorrect), and therefore if (ModelState.IsValid) is returning FALSE, please advise?

Comment: @Mick See the edit. You need to use `hiddenfield` if you need the values to be posted back to the controller.